# Проблемы с Support Library

Tags: java, android

Недавно начало вылезать такое:

> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.

В количестве 100500 штук в библиотеке Appcompat.

Все обновлено до последней версии, эклипс переустанавливался, библиотеку реимпортировал несколько раз, quick fix молчит.

Вопрос: что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версию API поменяй

Comment: На какую, не подскажете?

Comment: @Lucky, Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: > На какую, не подскажете?  

api, которым собирается проект на 21.

Comment: В самой библиотеке помогло,  а вот в моем проекте уже стоит 21,  но ошибки все равно есть.